# How fix error "Unexpected token" into Sapper project

Tags: javascript

I used `nvm` to switch node js from 10.14.1 to 10.15.3, started the project`npm run dev` and got an error.

```
C:\user\project>npm run dev
> sapper dev
 ✗ server
 Unexpected token (1:63) 
 ✗ client Unexpected token (1:63)
```

Did: remove and reinstall packages

```
> rm -rf `node_modules`
> npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax error into components.
If at the beginning into component `<button on:click></button>` add `=""` into end `on:click` and start project `npm run dev`, get error

```
C:\Users\admin\project> npm run dev         

> web_channel-mnp_om@0.0.1 dev C:\Users\admin\project
> sapper dev

✗ server
Unexpected token (1:63)
✗ client
Unexpected token (1:63)
```

If at the beginning run project `npm run dev` after into component `<button on:click></button>` add `=""` into end `on:click`, get error

```
(node:6220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined
    at _loop_1 (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:354:111)
    at new RollupResult (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:358:17)
    at class_1.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:528:46)
    at class_1.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Watcher.emit (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:38118:22)
    at C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:38163:19
(node:6220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6220) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
✗ client
Unexpected token (1:63)
(node:6220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'imports' of undefined
    at C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:267:15
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at extract_css (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:266:30)
    at RollupResult.to_json (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:394:18)
    at handle_result (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\dev.js:262:55)
    at C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\dev.js:346:17
    at class_1.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\sapper\dist\core.js:528:37)
    at class_1.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Watcher.emit (C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:38118:22)
    at C:\Users\admin\my-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:38163:19
(node:6220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Conclusion: Need to delete `=""`